# Changing ListBox selection is not moving changes from BindingSource to DataSet

Tags: visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, c#-2.0

The answer to this question may turn out to be, "Don't use typed DataSets without using the Binding Navigator."
I am curious, however, about the behavior I'm seeing.

So, I created a form where every control was dragged from the data sources explorer.
I deleted the Binding Navigator because it is ugly and inappropriate for this particular form.
I added a ListBox and set the DataSource to the BindingSource.
Notice that the ListBox is not bound, it is just filling itself from the BindingSource.
By some magic that I wasn't counting on, moving around in the ListBox is navigating the BindingSource and all other controls are updating accordingly.

I can make changes to the bound controls and explicitly call EndEdit on the BindingSource and then update the DataSource through the Table Adapter.  Works great.

When I make changes in the bound controls and click a new option in the ListBox, I want to be able to check for changes and prompt to save or reset if there are any.

Here is the strange part that I haven't been able to figure out.

No matter what event I attach to, DataSet.HasChanges doesn't return true until the second ListBox change.
I've searched and tried dozens of suggestions, most of them ridiculous, but a few that seemed promising.
No luck.

Edit: It isn't the second click that is significant, it is when you click back on the original (edited) item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since asking the question, I've learned a bit more about BindingSources, DataSets and TableAdapters.

Here is what works:

```
    private void MyListBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.myBindingSource.EndEdit();
        if (myDataSet.HasChanges())
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Save changes?", "Before moving on", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                myTableAdapter.Update(myDataSet.myDataTable);
            }
            else
            {
                myDataSet.RejectChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```